# How to extend end time of fullcalendar recurring events to the next day?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How can I show a recurring event in which the end time exceeds the current day?

Here's a sample data:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  title: "ABC",
  startRecur: "2020-06-11T16:00:00.000Z",
  startTime: "23:00:00",
  endTime: "03:00:00",
  daysOfWeek: ["5"]
};

calendar.addEventSource({
  events: [data]
});
```

Basically the start time is `11:00 PM` and should end the next day `3:00 AM`. How will I let `fullcalendar` know that it should end the next day? Take note that this is a recurring event.

Here's what it looks like in month view:

[image]

and in week view (event not rendered because it thinks that end time is 3 AM of same day):

[image]

[Here's a pen of the problem.](https://codepen.io/wobsoriano/pen/gOPbZqL)

I want it to look like this (google calendar)

[image]

**UPDATE:** Got it working using the [rrule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin)

Comment: fullcalendar's built-in recurring events are relatively limited in their functionality, so I don't think you can do it. Try using the rrule plugin instead, rrule is more flexible. I haven't got time to check it precisely not but I suspect you could probably achieve what you want more easily with rrule. It's worth looking into, anyway.

Comment: @ADyson hey thanks very much. After spending some time with fullcalendar's built-in recurring events, looks like it can't do what I want. And checking what you suggested, I think the rrule plugin will do it.

Comment: @ADyson yep, rrule plugin works <3

Comment: That's great. Maybe you could post an answer below, so others can benefit too?

Comment: @ADyson added, thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

So before, I was doing it using `fullcalendar's` built-in recurring events.

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  title: "ABC",
  startRecur: "2020-06-11T16:00:00.000Z",
  startTime: "23:00:00",
  // endTime is 03:00:00 because I expect it to end the next day at 3 AM
  endTime: "03:00:00",
  daysOfWeek: ["5"]
};

calendar.addEventSource({
  events: [data]
});
```

The problem with this is that when you have an `endTime` that is less than the given `startTime`, `fullcalendar` will not understand it and will not render the event in the calendar.

To fix this, there is a plugin called [rrule plugin](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin) which allow recurring events across days. Thanks to [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson).

Instead of the above way of adding recurring events, we can use this instead:

```js
const data = {
  id: 1,
  title: "my recurring event",
  rrule: {
    freq: "weekly",
    interval: 5,
    byweekday: ["fr"],
    // In the above code,
    // start date and start time are separate.
    // In the rrule plugin, dtstart
    // should contain both start date and time.
    dtstart: "2020-06-01T23:00:00"
  },

  // Duration is how long the event will run,
  // not exactly what the time it should end.
  // in our case, to end the event the next day 3 AM.
  // We should add 4 hours.
  duration: "04:00"
};

calendar.addEventSource({
  events: [data]
});
```

Here's a working [pen](https://codepen.io/wobsoriano/pen/gOPbZqL).